# Performing weighted sum overlay analysis in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, overlay, spatial-analysis

I have weighted raster data converted from polygons with different categories.

I have ArcGIS with 3D Analyst extension, unfortunately do not have Spatial Analyst, and I would like to use QGIS to make weighted sum overlay analysis, probably using ordered weighted averaging.

I found some similar questions but nearly all explained vector overlay analysis. Here grids (tif, img etc) will be used.

Answer (score 2):

*SAGA* has an **Ordered Weighted Averaging** tool which lets you import grids as an input. You can access this from the *Processing Toolbox*:

[image: Ordered weighted averaging tool]

The [QGIS documentation](http://docs.qgis.org/2.6/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/saga/grid_analysis/orderedweightedaveraging.html) for this tool appears blank, but there is some information in the [SAGA documentation](http://www.saga-gis.org/saga_module_doc/2.1.3/grid_analysis_11.html).