# Creating raster layers, weighting them, and combining them in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, raster-calculator, rasterization, combine

I'm looking to create raster layers from vector layers, rescale them, weight them then finally combine them for a final result.

I'm really not sure about the process to do this. On Arcmap it's really straight forward but on QGIS I'm having significant difficulty. This is the process I use on arcmap:
Vecter layer --> Eclidean Distance --> Rescale new layer using min-max score transformation on raster calculate --> combine all raster layers with Weighted Sum Tool.

I can't for the life of me figure out the same process in QGIS.

Comment: These posts should help point you in the right direction https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/21575/calculating-distance-to-points-in-qgis (Euclidean distance) https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/229796/reclassify-a-raster-file-with-quantiles?noredirect=1&lq=1 (reclassify) https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/138823/how-can-i-make-weighted-sum-overlay-analysis-in-qgis-ordered-weighted-averagi (weighted sum)